# Почему переменная не изменяется вне цикла?

Tags: python

Имеется цикл, который должен увеличивать переменную n пока вещественная часть комплекснного числа, после возведения в куб не станет равна еденице

```
n = 0
r = complex(n, 6)**3

while r.real != 1:
    print(r)
    n += .1
```

Проблема этого кода в том, что переменная r не изменяется и цикл становиться бесконечным. При том, что переменная n без осечек инкрементируется на на одну десятую

Comment: а вы уверены, что вещественная часть однажды станет равной единице?

Comment: абсолютно уверен

Comment: я лично вижу, что она отрицательная и растет по модулю (т.е. становится всё меньше) с каждым изменением n, удаляясь от 1. Но меняться начала - можете принять ответ (галка под треугольником слева от ответа):-)

Comment: вовзедение числа в степень это поворот, комлпексное число "повернётся" на n градусов пока вещественная часть не станет положительной

Comment: И сколько примерно (порядок) итераций нужно, чтобы она ей стала?

Comment: число complex(n, 12)**3 станет положительным при n = 21

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138497/discussion-between--and-user409986).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чисто технически ваш код должен бы выглядеть так, как ниже (теперь r пересчитывается после каждого изменения n, до этого она была вне цикла).
Решит ли это основную задачу - не знаю, но поставленную проблему ("Проблема этого кода в том, что переменная r не изменяется") решает.

```
n = 0
r = complex(6, n)**3

while r.real != 1:
    print(r)
    n += .1
    r = complex(6, n)**3
```

Answer (score 0):

При изменении переменной `n` переменная`r` и не должна меняться.

В строчке

```
r = complex(6, n)**3
```

вы просто создаёте объект типа `complex`, передавая в поля `real` и `imag` объекты объект 6 и переменную `n` (под которой лежит объект 0). В процессе присваивания в памяти создаются новые объекты типа float (6 и 0) и они сразу же передаются в поля комплексного числа. Так 'r.imag' становится 6, `r.real` становится равным 0. Объект, на который ссылается `n` и на которые ссылается `real` - два разных объекта и они меняются вне зависимости друг от друга.

Comment: очень сложное объяснение, я его вообще не понял:-) Возможно, оно даже просто ошибочное, так как  n, например, точно ни на что не ссылается, это же просто параметр. И что за 'imag' такой?

Comment: @Сергей изменил для непонятливых

Comment: Оскорбления, конечно, сильный метод, но лучше все же научиться верно формулировать свои мысли. Это база знаний, а не игра "Угадай мелодию".

Comment: Оскорбление это лишь точка восприятия человека. Невозможно кого-то оскорбить, но можно оскорбиться. И да, думаю Stack Overflow был создан для взаимной помощи программистам а не для выяснений чей ответ на вопрос лучше и кто кого "оскорбил"

Comment: Вот только сентенций ложной мудрости тут и не хватает. Если вы покроете кого-то матом публично, то вам (если возраст соответствует) судья по ч. 1 ст. 5.61 КоАП РФ вполне определит наказание за оскобление. Учитывая же, что я ничего не упоминал про "чей ответ на вопрос лучше", то теперь понятно, чем руководствовались вы, написав про "непонятливых" :-)) Я же как-то уже давно меряться чем-либо перестал. Закончу на этом, сайт не для подобных дискуссий. Не услышите - дело ваше:-)